# Recursive addition code in C

Tags: c

The following code works but I don't quite understand how ***if (*s == 0)*** works.
It checks if the string is 0?

Also for ***return(isnumber(s+1))*** what is the logic behind that? 
I know s is a string but I can just pass s+1 into a function? How does it even know what character I'm looking for?

```
int isnumber(char *s) {
    if (*s == 0) {
        return 1;  /* Reached end, we've only seen digits so far! */
    }
    if(!isdigit(*s)) {
        printf("The number is invalid\n");
        return 0;  /* first character is not a digit, so no go */
    }
    return(isnumber(s+1));
}


int main () {
    char inbuf[LENGTH];
    int i, j;

    printf("Enter a string > ");
    fgets(inbuf, LENGTH-1, stdin); // ignore carriage return
    inbuf[strlen(inbuf)-1] = 0;
    j = isnumber(inbuf);
....
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This function is a recursive function that checks if a string contains all numbers. To understand how the code works, you must understand how C stores strings. If you have the string "123", C stores this string in memory, like this:

```
|-----------------------------------|
| 0x8707 | 0x8708 | 0x8709 | 0x870A | 
|--------|--------|--------|--------|
|        |        |        |        |
|  '1'   |  '2'   |  '3'   | '\0'   |
|-----------------------------------|
```

What C does is it breaks your sting up into characters, stores them in some arbitrary location in memory and adds a null character `(\0)` (ASCII 0) to the end of the string. This null character is how C knows where the string ends.

Your `isnumber()` function takes a `char *s` as a parameter. This is called a pointer. Internally, whats going on is your `main()` function calls `isdigit()` and it actually passes in the **address of** your string, not the string itself. This is important:

```
j = isnumber(inbuf);
```

How the compiler interprets this is `call isnumber() and pass along the address of inbuf and assign the return value to j`.

Now back up at the `isnumber()` function, its receiving the address of `inbuf` and assigning it to `s`. By placing an asterisk `(*)` in front of `s`, you are doing something called **dereferencing** `s`. Dereferencing means you want the value contained at the address of `s`. So the line that says `if (*s == 0)` is basically saying `If the value contained at the address of s is equal to 0`. Remember earlier I told you in memory, strings always have a terminating null `(\0)` character? This is how your function knows to end and return.

The next thing to understand is **pointer arithmetic**. Depending on your system, a `char` might occupy either 1 byte of memory or 2 bytes. You can find out for sure by printing a `sizeof(char)`. But when you refer to `(s+1)`, that is telling the computer to take the memory address pointed to by `s` and add to it whatever the size of a `char` is. So if a `char` is 1 byte long and `s` is pointed to `0x8707`, then `(s+1)` will make `s` equal `0x8708` and `*s` will point to the '2' in our string (see my memory block diagram above). This is how we iterate through each character in the string.

Hopefully this clears up the confusion!

Comment: Love your explanation.  But to cover if char is 1 byte vs 2 bytes, shouldn't the line say: `(s + sizeof(s))` to be on the safe side?

Comment: @BlackFrog - No, because the compiler already knows the size of it, and so it automatically knows to move it 1 byte or 2 bytes. As far as the programmer is concerned, he or she shouldn't have to worry about the size. When you have `(s + 1)`, the compiler knows to move it 2, if `char` is 2 bytes long. It is important NOT to use `(s + sizeof(char)) because on a system where a `char` is 2 bytes long, this would equate to `(s + 2)`, which would actually move the pointer 4 bytes, instead of 2.

Comment: in C and C++, char is always 1 byte, but a byte can have more than 8 bits

Comment: @LưuVĩnhPhúc - That is true. According to C99, char is always 1 byte. I just wanted to make sure he understood how the pointer arithmetic worked though and never make assumptions.

Answer (score 1):

The statement `if (*s == 0)` checks to see if the `char` `s` points to is zero. In other words, it checks to see if `s` is a zero-length string and returns `1` if so.

The statement `return (isnumber(s+1))` adds `1` to s, causing it to point to the second `char` in the string, and passes that to `isnumber()`. `isnumber` returns true if the string at `s[1]` is a digit.

Comment: It's not checking for zero-LENGTH.  It's checking for [NULL character](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null_character)

Comment: @BlackFrog Right, and a null character in the first position of a string makes what?  Yup, an empty string.

Answer (score 0):

In C, strings are terminated with a null character.

`(*s == 0)`  is checking for the null terminator.

This code is a little weirder.

```
return(isnumber(s+1));
```

Since the current character is a digit, keep going...call the function again starting at the NEXT character.  This is a recursive function call and there is really no need when iteration would be simpler.